# how to disable a button in React imported into another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

it's my first application in react and I'm not sure how to disable an imported button.
I have a component button that I import into a parent component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../index.scss";

class Submit extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="button"
      onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
        SUBMIT
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Submit;
```

in the component that rendered it is as follows

```
  renderSubmit() {
    return (
      <Submit
        onClick={() => this.submitForm()}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
   
    return (
      <div className="table">
        <div className="table-actions">
            {this.renderRefresh()}
            {this.renderSubmit()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to set the class to disabled from the original component but it depends on a state property and does not recognize it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../index.scss";

class Submit extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="button"
      disabled={this.state.start}
      onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
        SUBMIT
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Submit;
```

How can I condition the disabled state to a state property?

Comment: I imagine you would be setting the state in `onClick()`, but, I don't see this function?  Can you please add it so I can take a look?

Comment: don,t have onclick function... in parent component calls this.submitForm().
Is this the problem? I have taken out the component of a tutorial and I don't know very well what the onclick is for

Comment: If you want the button to be disabled after click, then it needs to be coded in `onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>`.  Where is `onClick()`?  Why not try adding this function `onClick() {this.setState({'start':true});}` in your component and then `onClick={() => this.onClick()}` to your onClick caller, since it's not a prop anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Submit` button doesn't allow for setting any other props on the underlying `button` component. It should proxy though any props you want to be externally configured by what is rendering the `Submit` button. I also suggest explicitly declaring the button type to be "submit", or also exposing that prop out in the component API.

Your proxying of the `onClick` handler also drops the click event, that should be passed through in case any consuming component care about it.

```
class Submit extends Component {
  render() {
    const { disabled, onClick, type = "submit" } = this.props;
    return (
      <button
        className="button"
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={onClick}
        type={type}
      >
        SUBMIT
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

For such a simple component with no internal logic IMO a functional component is a better option, and I would name it more clearly.

```
const SubmitButton = ({ disabled, onClick, type = "submit" }) => (
  <button
    className="button"
    disabled={disabled}
    onClick={onClick}
    type={type}
  >
    SUBMIT
  </button>
);
```

Now when you are using the submit button from a parent component you can pass in a `disabled` prop based on any condition you need/require.

```
  render() {
    const { submitDisabled } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="table">
        <div className="table-actions">
          {this.renderRefresh()}
          <SubmitButton
            disabled={submitDisabled} // <-- pass disabled value
            onClick={this.submitForm} // <-- attach click handler
            type="button" // <-- so we don't accidentally take default form action
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How you compute/set `this.state.submitDisabled` is up to you. Maybe it is disabled when the form is being submitted, for example.

```
submitForm = () => {
  this.setState({ submitDisabled: true });
  ...
};
```